# Parameterized MySql Query in vb.net Not Passing to DB

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Cant seem to get this to pass to the data base I assume there is an issue with the query any help is appreciated.There are no errors given by VS , that leads me to think the issue is with the statement, sadly i cannot test it in navicat because its not "true values" I tried using parameters like this

Params.Add(New MySqlParameter("@eventDate", eventDate))

and paramiters like this

Params.Add(New MySqlParameter("eventDate", eventDate))

Same results from both

```
Public Function ParameterizedNonQueryCommand(ByRef NonQuery As String, ByVal Parameters As List(Of MySqlParameter), _
        Optional ByVal Connection As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection = Nothing) As Integer

        Dim comm As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(NonQuery, Connection)
        Try
            For Each param As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter In Parameters
                comm.Parameters.Add(param)
            Next
            If comm.Connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then comm.Connection.Open()
            comm.Prepare()
            Return comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return CType(False, Integer)
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            comm.Connection.Close()
            comm.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Function



Dim query As String = "insert into so_events (date, user, ip, method, event, Staffed, Details, BackgroundColor, TextColor, Recurring, Font, TextSize, ToolTip)" _
                           & "values (@eventDate, @User, @ip, @ControlPanel, @EventName, @staffed, @cpEvents, @BackColor, @TextColor, @Recurring, @fontStyle, @fontSize, @allowTool)"
            Dim Params As New List(Of MySqlParameter)
            Params.Add(New MySqlParameter("@eventDate", eventDate))
            Params.Add(New MySqlParameter("@User", frmMain.user))
            Params.Add(New MySqlParameter("@ControlPanel", "ControlPanel"))
            Params.Add(New MySqlParameter("@EventName", eventName))
            Params.Add(New MySqlParameter("@staffed", staffed))
            Params.Add(New MySqlParameter("@cpEvents", cpEvents))
            Params.Add(New MySqlParameter("@BackColor", BackColor))
            Params.Add(New MySqlParameter("@TextColor", TextColor))
            Params.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Recurring", Recurring))
            Params.Add(New MySqlParameter("@fontStyle", fontStyle))
            Params.Add(New MySqlParameter("@fontSize", fontSize))
            Params.Add(New MySqlParameter("@allowTool", allowTool))

            Dim oConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=********;Database=*******;User ID=********;Password=*********;")
            frmPanel.ParameterizedNonQueryCommand(query, Params, oConnection)
```

Comment: Have you tried `comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventDate", eventDate);`

Comment: That looks like an attempt at some sort of helper routine. Can you get it to work as a single method? The number of param is off though - 13 in the query but only 12 provided.  You also have DB Object not being disposed of.